# Hard drive in caddy doesn't show up on My PC/Computer anymore

Tags: windows, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I had to take hard drive out to do some work with another hard drive. After I was done with that, I put my original hard drive back and now it doesn't show up on My PC/Computer anymore (file explorer).

It appears to be "working properly" in the Device Manager. Besides, when I open the disk management tool and see yellow exclamation mark and no size or any other info about the disk.

I cannot format it since I have very important files inside. Is there any other solutions that I should try before I give up? I can hear it working, it doesn't seem to be completely dead.

Any hopes?

And interestingly this program called Crystal Disk shows it status without a problem

[image: status]

[image: my pc]

[image: properties]

[image: disk management]

[image: device manager]

Comment: You mean that you see the yellow exclamation mark in Device Manager? Could you add a screenshot?

Comment: @harrymc added them. And when I check the properties of the device on device manager, it says 'your device is working properly' :/

Comment: I understand that the disk is the one that is marked "Foreign". Try: In Disk Management, right-click the Foreign disk and select "Import Foreign Disks".

Comment: @harrymc Thanks mate! At the same time :)

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it finally. Just right clicked on the hard drive on disk management window and then clicked import foreign disks.. Now I can go to sleep!